# LEFT JOIN is NULL condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, left-join

I have been struggling to left join a table in which has a condition of IS NULL in it. But the result of the query gets a NULL data.

```
SELECT users.id, employees.id as empid, users.activated_at, users.created_at
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN users on users.login = employees.employeeid
WHERE users.activated_at IS NULL
ORDER BY users.created_at ASC
```

After having sql syntax I end up having this query. I'm just want to get the users that is not yet activated and has an employee data. But I always end up getting employees with NULL user data.

Comment: You need to do an `INNER JOIN` if you do not want employees with NULL user data.

Comment: INNER JOIN seem to work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an `INNER JOIN` if you do not want employees with NULL user data.

```
SELECT users.id, 
       employees.id AS empid, 
       users.activated_at, 
       users.created_at 
FROM   employees 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON users.login = employees.employeeid 
WHERE  users.activated_at IS NULL 
ORDER  BY users.created_at ASC
```

The `INNER JOIN` will exclude records that don't exist in both tables. So any employee that doesn't have user data will be excluded. `LEFT JOIN` is different as it will return all matching records from the first table (employees) regardless of whether or not they matched on users (there WHERE condition is still TRUE in these cases), so some will have fully NULL user data.

Comment: Thank you very much. INNER JOIN seem to work and also thank you for giving me details on how these joins work.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL seems to work for me: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a8ac/1)

Comment: I think what he meant [was this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b729/1) when there is employee with no user data. That is when type of JOIN matters.

Comment: You could be right, but he did say "I'm just want to get the users that is not yet activated and has an employee data." Given that he has an `activated_at` column, I thought that it would be null when "not yet activated" - he is even testing for that in the SQL. If he had no row in users when the employee wasn't activated, but wanted that employee to still be in the results, he should have said that. Sigh.